# Vista Networking Not Working...Can't even ping localhost

Tags: windows-vista, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vista Networking Not Working…Can’t even ping localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/88628/vista-networking-not-workingcant-even-ping-localhost)

I'm trying to fix a friends laptop running Vista.  He told me his wireless networking wasn't working which I confirmed.  I then tried the ethernet NIC and it also didn't work.  I am unable to even ping localhost/127.0.0.1.  I noticed when I issue an "ipconfig /all" command the assigned IP comes back with:

```
169.254.238.242 (Preferred)
```

My understanding is this comes back when the computer can't get an IP address using DHCP.  I even tried assigning a static IP address (192.168.1.x for my home network) but no luck.  I did some research and found this seems not to be an uncommon problem.    I notice there are a lot of tunnels, etc.  I'm not a big Vista guy so I'm not exactly sure what's going on here.  I even tried upgrading the driver for the ethernet controller but no luck.  I figure since it's happening with both wireless and the ethernet conroller it has something more to do with the the OS/dirver configuration.  Here is the entire output of the ipconfig /all command:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6001]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Brent-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet
 Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-E0-B8-FC-DE-81
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.238.242(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR5B91 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-22-69-8F-1A-AB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 6:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{9F10C518-8D3F-40BF-9D1B-15A8FDD95
808}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 7:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{5559AAD9-B5EF-4392-A7B3-D9DF2A2B8
60E}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{62E497EB-9F7D-4AA8-A696-3D1AAB6F9
C03}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{15C75D20-E062-4983-8152-98017F1D1
A56}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: I would ask this on superuser.com.

Comment: hm. superuser would be a more appropriate place i suppose.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/88628/vista-networking-not-workingcant-even-ping-localhost/88646#88646.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [reinstalling the TCP/IP stack](http://www.zimbio.com/Windows+Vista/articles/43/Reinstall+Reset+TCP+IP+Internet+Protocol+Windows) following these steps for Vista:

1. Click on **Start** button.
2. Type **Cmd** in the Start Search text box.
3. Press **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** keyboard shortcut to run Command Prompt as Administrator. Allow elevation request.
4. Type **netsh int ip reset** in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key.
5. Restart the computer.

The command will remove all user configured settings on TCP/IP stack and return it to original default state by rewriting pertinent registry keys that are used by the Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) stack to achieve the same result as the removal and the reinstallation of the protocol. The registry keys affected are:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\

and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCP\Parameters\

--More information on Microsoft's site [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357).